# Customizing harvard bibliography style apsr

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style, custom-bib

The apsr style is almost what I need to comply to our totally unique Harvard style based University referencing requirements. I need to make the following customizations:

For displaying authors the specified format for apsr is

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author #1 "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f}" format.name$           
      "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" author format.rem.names
    }
  if$
}
```

I need all authors to follow the style "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f}". When I try to change the line `"{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" author format.rem.names` to `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f}" author format.rem.names`I do not get any change :( . Should I change another function as well?

Example bibtex:

```
    @article{wang2015cyber
,   author  = {Wang, Lihui and T\"orngren, Martin and Onori, Mauro}
,   title   = {Current status and advancement of cyber-physical systems in manufacturing}
,   journal = {Journal of Manufacturing Systems}
,   year    = {2015}
,   publisher   = {Elsevier}
}
```

Output
[image]

I would like to have it:

WANG, L., TORNGEREN M. & ONORI M. 2015. ect...

I am quite new and the only one using latex at my University it seems, everybody is using MS WORD . I am trying to build a template for post graduate students.

here is a link to the original  [apsr.bst](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/apsr.pdf)

Comment: Have you cleaned the auxiliary files before running your new `bst` file? I tried your suggestion and it changed the order of names mostly as expected...

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. It seems I have to save over the original file. I can not change the name of the .bst file and keep it in the same directory. I think I will try custom-bib in anycase.

Comment: Actually you *must* give the file another name according to the license header, and then you just need to change the `\bibliographystyle` call to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you, can you please elaborate on how I can change the name of the .bst file according to the licence header. Sorry everything I tried did not work.

Comment: If I rename the file "apsrTUT", and change the '\bibliographystyle{apsrTUT}' it does not generate a bibliography.  I have included the natbib package and the har2nat package.

Comment: It's probably a problem with old auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, etc). Make sure to clean them before compilation. I added an answer with all the suggestions above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apsr.bst` license requires

> if you do make changes, you name it something other than btxbst.doc, plain.bst, unsrt.bst, alpha.bst, abbrv.bst, agsm.bst, dcu.bst or kluwer.bst, jmr.bst, apsr.bst.
>
> This restriction helps ensure that all standard styles are identical.

So, if you intend to change it, you should rename the file to something else. Following your suggestion, let's call it `apsrTUT.bst`.

I copied the original file and renamed it with (in a unix-like environment):

```
cp `kpsewhich apsr.bst` apsrTUT.bst
```

(`kpsewhich` finds the file in the texlive tree so that I don't have to look for it; it actually resides in `$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/harvard/apsr.bst`)

Then I applied the change you mentioned; here's the `diff` for the original `apsr.bst` to the new `apsrTUT.bst`:

```
201c201
<       "{ff }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" author format.rem.names
---
>       "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f}" author format.rem.names
```

We must then pass the new style file to the `bibliographystyle` call in our file

```
\bibliographystyle{apsrTUT}
```

If you've done this and it still isn't working, make sure to delete the external auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.blg`, `.log`) before compiling the document again.

---

Here's a MWE (with the packages you mentioned in your comments):

<sup>The `filecontents` environment used here allows one to ship an external file (here the bibliographic database, `\jobname.bib`) within the document. It is used here only to provide a fully compilable example.</sup>

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{wang2015cyber,
    author = {Wang, Lihui and T\"orngren, Martin and Onori, Mauro},
    title = {Current status and advancement of cyber-physical systems in manufacturing},
    journal = {Journal of Manufacturing Systems},
    year = {2015},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\begin{document}
\cite{wang2015cyber}
\bibliographystyle{apsrTUT}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

> [image: mwe sample]