# Modifying agsm.bst package bibliography output

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to change the URL output **from:**

URL: the html link

**into:**

[Online]URL: [Accessed on]

I am using:

```
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262158/5872) I have explained the
step by step to modify another bst from the harvard bundle; please refer
to it for the step-by-step.

`agsm.bst` does not provide a urldate field, so you'd have to add by
yourself to a modified bibtex style. I created the `agsm-url.bst` from
the original `agsm.bst` and added a `urldate` field to it as in [this
answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7383/5872). The diff:

```
43a44
>     urldate
165c166,171
<     { "\newline\harvardurl{" URL * "}" * write$ newline$ }
---
>     { "\newline\harvardurl{" URL * "}" * write$ newline$ 
>     urldate empty$
>       { skip$ }
>       { "[Accessed on: " urldate * "]" * write$ newline$ }
>       if$
>     }
```

<sup>If you don't want the linebreak before the URL block, just delete the `\newline`</sup>

Then I redefined the `\harvardurl` macro with

```
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{[Online] URL: \textit{#1}}
```

<sup>See [this answer about redefining it to add hyperlinks with `hyperref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9450/5872)</sup>

Here's a MWE:

```
% Adapted bib file from tugboat.bib
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{online,
    author = {Robert Welland},
    title = {{Editor's Comments}},
    journal = {TUGboat},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    pages = {2--3},
    month = oct,
    year = {1980},
    ISSN = {0896-3207},
    urldate = {Fri Jul 13 10:24:20 MDT 2007},
    url = {http://www.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/tugboat.bib}
  }
  @article{offline,
    author = {Richard Palais},
    title = {{Message from the Chairman}},
    journal = {TUGboat},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    pages = {3--7},
    month = oct,
    year = {1980},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
% natbib.sty, line 1042:
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{[Online] URL: \textit{#1}}
\begin{document}
\cite{online,offline}
\bibliographystyle{agsm-url}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

> [image: mwe sample]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. However I am facing a problem because of the bst file. While I am tryinf to generate the bibtex I am having an error "pte=20, stack='20---the literal stack isnt empty for entry online while executing---line 1349 of file agsm-url.bst

Comment: I tried so many alternatives by the same error keeps happening with the .bst file. I even tried the example file you posted as it is:                            ptr=2, stack=
'20
0
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry online
while executing---line 1350 of file agsm-url.bst

Comment: I just did it again here with no errors. What I've done is: 1. I copied the diff and put it in an `agsm-url.diff` file; 2. I copied the `agsm.bst` locally with a `cp \`kpsewhich agsm.bst\` agsm-url.bst`; 3. I patched the new `agsm-url.bst` file with the `diff` file mentioned before with `patch agsm-url.bst < agsm-url.diff`; 4. I copied the MWE and compiled it perfectly.

Comment: In case anybody has problems applying the patch, the patched file is at https://gist.github.com/moewew/6c65c256c9420d64f3b264c0a78774c0