# Citation Style for Web Pages

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

I am looking for a biblioraphy style that adds to the type `webpage` from `BibDesk` the attribute `Last accessed`. 
Is there an out of the box citation style doing this? If not, how can I add it to a citation style? Currently I am using `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` which only includes the `URL`, but no `Last accessed` attribute. I get

> Warning--entry type for ... isn't style-file defined of file ref.bib

Comment: Am I right to assume you are open to biblatex solutions, as your tags indicate? In this case, it's available out of the box, and called `urldate`. (But, if you are not open to that, please retag your question).

Comment: @gusbrs Sure. How does it go? Is there a way to do it without `biblatex` too?

Comment: @gusbrs it would be better to do it with the stack I am using already though. `BibDesk` and `\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}`

Comment: Well, for a natbib solution I'd not be well equipped. I'm also not acquainted with Bibdesk...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262464/35864

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the link, but that doenst work... I get the same errors the commentors get. I also tried the command line approach by merging the diff into the file. That does not work neither. It stops with an error.

Comment: @gusbrs Could you share your `biblatex` solution?

Comment: How did it not work? What exactly did you try? At what step did things go wrong?

Comment: @moewe I manually copied the lines into the `.bst` file which gives me this `---the literal stack isn't empty for entry williams2015
while executing---line 1351 of file agsm-url.bst
ptr=3, stack=
'21
'20
0
`

Comment: I have also done this "1. I copied the diff and put it in an agsm-url.diff file; 2. I copied the agsm.bst locally with a cp `kpsewhich agsm.bst` agsm-url.bst; 3. I patched the new agsm-url.bst file with the diff file with patch agsm-url.bst < agsm-url.diff" . Step three throws me this `patching file agsm-url.bst
Hunk #2 FAILED at 366.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file agsm-url.bst.rej` *OR* `patching file agsm-url.bst
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** unexpected end of file in patch at line 10` if I dont include a `\n` as last line in `.diff` file .

Comment: You must patch the files such that you end up with https://gist.github.com/moewew/6c65c256c9420d64f3b264c0a78774c0

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the link. Copy & Pasting your code in `raw` and inserting it did the trick...