# Citation Style including web pages

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am using `BibDesk` and `natbib` for my references.

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

The bibliographystyle `agsm` does not include webpages. Which citation style includes webpages and the attribute last checked, accessed, ... and is similar to `agsm`?

Comment: What about https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426968/35864? How is this question different from the one you asked about two hours ago?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262464/35864